# Maximum Impulse that can be imparted without losing contact

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws

[image: 1]

> I don't really know where to approach this problem  from,Though I think solving might be easier in centre of mass frame.
> What are your thoughts?
> Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that the author of the problem is considering the gravitational force between the two spheres.  Then you are looking for the momentum of a circular orbit.

Comment: I don't understand why you say so eventhough I think you are correct.Could you please explain your answer.

Comment: The impulse is shown as coming from below. Without an attracting force any impulse would cause an immediate loss of contact.  Now that I think about it, mass B would move, and a circular orbit would be a valid oversimplification only initially.  You may need to consider the angular momentum of mass A relative to the center of mass. (Note: if the contact at the surface is friction-less, neither sphere will rotate.)